# Some HTML pages text scaling on mobile and others not

Tags: html, mobile, text, web

I have a website for my business coded entirely in HTML.  No CSS at all.  The problem is that every page except my index.html home page is scaling the text (on android) and reflowing it so that it is a readable size on the page.

So my question is: how would I go about making my website display properly on mobile devices using only HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you evaluated if using a viewport meta tag would suffice for your needs ?
https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html

I believe chrome supports the viewport tag as well.

Comment: Aha!  Brilliant!  That's exactly what I was looking for.  Just for reference, added this line to my <head> `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">` which scales everything beautifully on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to build a responsive website using only HTML. You need things like CSS and jQuery to make it responsive.

If you post your code, I will give you a few examples on incorporating more of a responsive design.